# How do I transfer parameters when I close a page in swift5?

Tags: ios, swift, parameter-passing

I'm currently working on Swift5. I have a question. There is currently a WebView launch and a custom notification window to check the data. I am closing the notification window after checking the data.

How do I forward data to a WebView page when I close the notification window here? I don't think it's a good way to refresh the WebView page. Is there any other way?

**WebView.swift** Open Modal Custom Alert

```swift
      let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let myAlert = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CheckAlertController") as! CheckAlertController
        myAlert.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        myAlert.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        self.present(myAlert, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

**Modal Custom Alert.swift**

```swift
    @IBAction func okButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I want to deliver data when I press OK button and close Modal Notification Window.

How can I solve problem ?

Is there any other way? What is the correct method?

For example,I receive data that I enter in a text field in the Custom Alerts pane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this code to the top of your Modal View Controller

```
protocol CheckAlertControllerDelegate: class {
    func handleData(_ data: String) // String for example
}
```

Add this code anywhere inside your Modal View Controller

```
weak var delegate: CheckAlertControllerDelegate?
```

Modify your ok button

```
@IBAction func okButton(_ sender: Any) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        delegate?.handleData("Your data here")
    })
}
```

In your web page before open the Modal add this line

```
myAlert.delegate = self
self.present(myAlert, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

And add this to your web page vc

```
extension YourWebPageViewController: CheckAlertControllerDelegate {
    func handleData(_ data: String) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I need to receive data from the web view screen, not from the web page.

Comment: For example,I receive data that I enter in a text field in the Custom Alerts pane

Comment: Oh, ok. I updated my answer. Just a little misunderstanding

Answer (score 2):

Modal Custom Alert.swift

```
var callBack: (()->())?

@IBAction func okButton(_ sender: Any) {
    callBack?()
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

WebView.swift

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let myAlert = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CheckAlertController") as! CheckAlertController
 myAlert.callBack = {
  // Execute your code
 }
 myAlert.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
 myAlert.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
 self.present(myAlert, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you give me an example of callback? I can't think of what to do.

Comment: For example,I receive data that I enter in a text field in the Custom Alerts pane

Comment: @hongdevelop in this case you should just add needed parameters in the closure:
var callBack: ((String)->())? then you could pass data in okButton function  callBack?(textToPass). In WebView just add myAlert.callBack = { textToPass in
  //handle it here
 }

Comment: If I close the modal, will I come in the callBack?

Comment: @hongdevelop not sure what you mean:  as a first step - callBack will call and will catch the result in your WebView, and only after this, you will close your view - so it will not interrupt code inside of the closure in WebView if you worry about this

Comment: When I enter the data and close the modal window, my data is 'myAlert.callBack = {
// Execute your code
Are you saying you're coming in here?

Comment: @hongdevelop yes, you can catch them in this alternative way instead of using delegates, I can attach an example in another answer below if you want

Comment: @ATV  Oh~Realiy? Thanks Then, can you give me an example? I don't have a good understanding

Answer (score 1):

This answer is pretty the same as @Jaydeep left, just to clarify to @hongdevelop more detailed

Modal Custom Alert.swift

```
var callBack: ((_ dataToPass: String)->())?

@IBAction func okButton(_ sender: Any) {
    //1 step: you will pass you string throw the closure, so you will catch it in your WebView 
    callBack?(textToPass) 
    // 2 step: closing the window as a later event will not interrupt passing data above
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

WebView.swift

```
...
let myAlert = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CheckAlertController") as! CheckAlertController


// defining a closure to catch a callback 
myAlert.callBack = { dataToPass in // define dataToPass in closure`s capture list
  // Handle your code
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the full explanation.